# Probability related to exclusion inclusion principle of three sets

Tags: probability

> In a group consisting of 40 students, 22 of them join in IMO, 17 students join in IBO, and 20 students join in ICO. Meanwhile there are several students join in two events in which IMO and IBO, IMO and ICO, and IBO and ICO are respectively followed by the number of 12, 8, and 8 students. Furthermore, there are 5 students who join at all three events.
>
> What is the probability of selecting one student who doesn't join at IBO and ICO?

My process of the solution is only making the symbols of the statements in the problem i.e.

M = IMO, B = IBO, C = ICO
$n(S) = 40$, $n(M) = 22$,   $n(B) = 17$,  $n(C) = 20$,
$$n(M \wedge B) = 12$$
$$n (M\wedge C) = 8$$
$$n(B \wedge C) = 8$$
$$n(M\wedge B\wedge C) = 5$$

I attempt with this
$$P(B \wedge C)'  = 1 - P(B \cup C) = 1 - [P(B) + P(C) - P(B\wedge C)]$$

is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for the probability that the chosen student is not attaining IBO and ICO (but he is allowed to attain all 3)? Then you are interested in $1-\mathbb{P}[\text{IBO and ICO but not IMO}]=\mathbb{P}[\text{IBO and ICO}]-\mathbb{P}[\text{IBO and ICO and IMO}]=\frac{8}{40}-\frac{5}{40}=\frac{3}{40}$

In general you just have to count the guys in the partition. Best way is to draw 3 circles in a general position (hence they all intersect each other) and then find the number of students in all the areas!

For example for the students only doing IBO: There are 5 students doing all three courses, hence there are 8-3=5 who only do ICO and IBO (but not all 3) and 12-5=7 who only do IBO and IMO. Since 17 people took the IBO cours and 5 of them do all three, 7 IBO and IMO and 3 do IBO and ICO, you know that there are only 2 guys doing IBO and nothing more.

Similary you get that the "only ICO", "only IMO" students are 9, resp. 7. By adding all disjoint events you see that only 36 students attain a class.

Now you can easily calculate any probability just by adding the numbers in the right partitions and dividing by 40.